# Setting root namespace when creating a .NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

When creating a .NET Core project I noticed that the namespaces will follow whatever you call the project.

For example:

- If I name the project `API` the root namespace will be `Hello`
- If I name the project `MyCompany.Hello.API` the root namespace will be `MyCompany.Hello.API` which is what I want it to be

I think I found a way to get the best of both worlds (short project names and preferred namespace) and it is to set the `RootNamespace` in the `.csproj` file after running the command:

```
dotnet new webapi -n API

<RootNamespace>MyCompany.Hello.API</RootNamespace>
```

I noticed after this is set it does exactly what I want when I create a new class file.

The reason for this post is that I want to see if there is anything wrong with doing this and to make sure this is what the setting is meant for. Is it best practice to create each project with the full namespace as the name or is it better to create a project with just a simple name and deal with the namespace manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with this approach.  I use it quite liberally.

For example, I may declare Commands and Queries in different assemblies so those assemblies can be managed by different devs.  But I may want a client assembly that references these to find the Commands and Queries in the same namespace:

Assembly: "MyApp.DomainA.Queries" will use default namespace "MyApp.DomainA".

Assembly: "MyApp.DomainA.Commands" will use default namespace "MyApp.DomainA".

Comment: By default namespace what do you mean and how are you setting it? Do you use Visual Studio or VSCode? Do you use the RootNamespace tags in the csproj files?

Comment: When I say "default namespace", I am referring to "root namespace".  I use Visual Studio and setting the root namespace is implemented with the RootNamespace tag in the csproj file as per the example in your original post.  In Visual Studio this can either be done manually by editing the csproj file or by: 1) Right-Click on Project,  2) Click 'Properties', 3) Update "Default namespace" field under Application > General > Default namespace, which is just a UI way of creating the RootNamespace tag in the csproj file.